# Post view count not updating with WP Super Cache

Tags: wordpress, view, count, browser-cache

I used this code to get the post count and works fine till I installed and enabled WP Super Cache. Once I installed and setup WP Super Cache, post count is not updating anymore.

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache via settings in wordpress plugin everytime you add a new post. Also there is a setting to clear a cache everytime post is published.

Comment: Setting already enabled and it is already clearing the cache when new post is published.